# Redistributing times

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Original problem:**
Given \$x\$ number of tests that should run in \$y\$ number of seconds shift the time per test so that each test takes a little longer than the next.

**Example:** If running 10 tests over 10 seconds, the equal time per test would be 1 second each.
Instead, have the first test take .5 seconds and the last test take 1.5 seconds while each subsequent test take a progressively longer duration.  We shift the time per test around while still maintaining the original duration of 10 seconds for the 10 tests.

I am slightly ignorant of what math principles are occurring.  I knew *how* I wanted to solve the problem but I can't *describe* the problem. I've made it possible to adjust how much shifting can be done.  Since the array of times is linear (and we can't really have negative times) I put a limit on that 'shifting' value.

1. How do you describe this function / math problem?  (which would hopefully result in a better name for it).
2. What should the `pct` variable be called?  I originally thought it to be a percentage of each second, but as I developed the function I realized this was inaccurate; since after the first value, the percentage of shifting per time slice goes down then back up again.

```py
def duration_spread(tests: float, seconds: float, pct: float = .75):
    assert -1 <= pct <= 1, "pct must be within +/-100% otherwise it will push times into negative"
    pct *= 2
    original_velocity = seconds/tests
    seconds_per_tests = original_velocity  # couldn't decide on naming convention
    average_velocity = original_velocity
    diff_average_velocity = pct * average_velocity
    acceleration = diff_average_velocity/tests

    multiplier_list = get_multipliers(tests)
    results = []
    for i, multiplier in enumerate(multiplier_list):
        newadjustment = (multiplier * acceleration)
        newtime = original_velocity + newadjustment
        print(f"{original_velocity} -> {newtime} :: {abs(newadjustment)}")
        results.append(newtime)

    return results


def get_multipliers(tests: float):
    odd = int(tests % 2)
    half_tests = int(tests // 2)
    result = list(range(-half_tests, half_tests+1))
    if not odd:
        result.pop(half_tests)
    return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This first, superficial refactor does the following:

- Rearrange functions in order of dependency
- Represent the return value of `get_multipliers` as a range and not a list for greater efficiency
- You're accepting a fraction, not a percentage; your inputs are -1 through 1, not -100 through 100
- some minor variable name abbreviations
- convert `duration_spread` to a generator
- delete some unused variables
- do not debug-print within your routine
- show the results in a test method

This gets us to

```
from typing import Iterable, Sequence


def get_multipliers(n_tests: int) -> Sequence[float]:
    odd = int(n_tests % 2)
    half_tests = int(n_tests // 2)
    if odd:
        yield from range(-half_tests, half_tests+1)
    else:
        yield from range(-half_tests, 0)
        yield from range(1, half_tests + 1)


def duration_spread(n_tests: int, seconds: float, frac: float = .75) -> Iterable[float]:
    assert -1 <= frac <= 1, "frac must be within +/-100%"
    orig_velocity = seconds / n_tests
    diff_avg_velocity = frac * 2 * orig_velocity
    accel = diff_avg_velocity / n_tests

    multipliers = get_multipliers(n_tests)
    for multiplier in multipliers:
        adj = multiplier * accel
        new_time = orig_velocity + adj
        yield new_time


def test():
    new_times = tuple(duration_spread(10, 10, .5))
    print(new_times)
    print(sum(new_times))


test()
```

Do some math and you'll see that for a series of \$n\$ integers, the total is:

\$
\sigma = \sum _1 ^n i = \frac {n(n+1)} 2
\$

If you introduce a spacing parameter \$\alpha\$ and base offset \$\delta\$, this becomes

\$
\sigma = \sum _1 ^n \left(\alpha i + \delta\right) = \frac {\alpha n(n+1)} 2 + n\delta
\$

Since your \$\alpha\$ and \$n\$ are fixed, you need to solve for \$\delta\$:

\$
\delta = \frac \sigma n - \frac {\alpha(n+1)} 2
\$

Applying this to some simplified code yields the correct results:

```
from math import isclose
from typing import Iterable


def duration_spread(n_tests: int, seconds: float, alpha: float) -> Iterable[float]:
    delta = seconds/n_tests - alpha*(n_tests - 1)/2
    for i in range(n_tests):
        yield delta + i*alpha


def test():
    times = tuple(duration_spread(10, 20, .3))
    total = sum(times)
    print(' + '.join(f'{x:.1f}' for x in times), f'= {total:.1f}')

    assert isclose(total, 20)
    for i in range(1, 10):
        assert isclose(.3, times[i] - times[i-1])


test()
```

```
 0.7 + 1.0 + 1.2 + 1.6 + 1.9 + 2.1 + 2.5 + 2.8 + 3.0 + 3.4 = 20.0
```

As an exercise to you: to re-introduce validation now that we're using a spacing parameter instead of a fraction, what would be an upper bound on the spacing parameter? You were in the right direction in chat; the criterion boils down to verifying that `delta > 0`.

Comment: `this should output 10 but actually outputs 9.5`. Right, but OP's original code outputs 10.

Comment: @Marc Good catch; I've fixed that regression. Thanks.

Comment: This is thoughtfully considered.  A new problem arises in your refactored version whereby the returned durations contain negative values when the number of tests exceeds the number of seconds.  If I plug in 10 seconds for 20 tests with an alpha of .3, the first 9 values returned are negative.  It was this problem alone caused me to realize I didn't know what the argument `pct` actually was.

Comment: That's why I've included my last sentence about upper bounds :)

Comment: Try `duration_spread(20, 10, .02)`. The number of tests exceeds the number of seconds and the output is correct.

Comment: To answer your question, I think only upper bound to the spacing value should be the total number of seconds. I can see now, my limit was based on how much of each slice could be taken off; e.g. the limit was the size of each slice. The lower bounds on the returned seconds between tests ought to be 0.

Comment: Part of my issue in trying to understand the problem is I never took calculus. (which is making it much hard to even discuss, let alone solve)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118458/discussion-between-reinderien-and-marcel-wilson).

Answer (score 2):

> How do you describe this function / math problem?

The input is a list of tests with the same duration. For example, \$input=[2,2,2,2]\$. Given the indexes from 0 to 3, we can see it in a graph:

[image]

So we can define the input as a (discrete) function \$f(x)=2\$, or in general \$f(x) = seconds/tests\$. Where \$0<=x<=tests,x∈Z\$.

The function \$durationSpread\$ can be described as \$durationSpread = g(x) * f(x)\$. Where \$g(x)\$ is a function that depends on \$pct\$ and \$tests\$. In the following I am going to refer it as \$g(pct,tests)\$.

### Function analysis

For `pct=0` the input remains the same: \$g(pct,tests) * input = g(0,4) * [2,2,2,2] = [2, 2, 2, 2]\$. Meaning that all elements of the input are multiplied by 1. So \$g\$ should look like this:
[image]

For `pct=-1` the result "should be": \$g(-1,4) * [2,2,2,2] = [4.0, 2.67, 1.33, 0.0]\$. The first element of of the input is multiplied by 2, the last one by 0, and the elements in between by a descending factor.

I said "should be" because your code outputs \$[4.0,3.0,1.0,0.0]\$, which is not possible if we consider a constant factor (the gap betweenn 4.0 and 3.0 is 1, but between 3.0 and 1.0 is 2).

So \$g\$ should look like this:
[image]
For `pct=1` the result is: \$g(1,4) * [2,2,2,2] = [0.0, 1.33, 2.67, 4.0]\$. In this case, the first element is multiplied by 0 and the last one by 2. So the function \$g\$ is:
[image]

How to find \$g\$? From the three examples, we know that \$g\$ is a **linear function**. A linear function can be represented as `y = mx + b`. How to find `m` and `b`? They can be found given two points.

Let's choose the first point `(x0,y0)` in the origin. `x0` is always 0. While `y0` depends on `pct`. Looking at the examples, we can tell that it's equal to `abs(pct - 1)`. Explanation:

- In the first example `pct=0` and `y0=1`. In fact, `y0 = abs(0 - 1) = 1`
- In the second example `pct=-1` and `y0=2`. In fact, `y0 = abs(- 1 - 1) = abs(-2) = 2`
- In the third example `pct=1` and `y0=0`. In fact, `y0 = abs(1 - 1) = abs(0) = 0`

For the second point `(x1,y1)`, we can choose the center. Where `y1` is always 1. While `x1` can be found as `x1 = (tests-1)/2`. (You can double-check in the three examples).

Given two points we can find the **slope** `m` as `m = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)`. Once we have `m`, we calculate the **constant** `b` as `b = y0 - (m * x0)`.

Now that we found \$g\$, we can multiply the input by \$g\$.

```py
def duration_spread(tests, seconds, pct):
    x0, y0 = 0, abs(pct - 1)
    x1, y1 = (tests - 1) / 2, 1
    m = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)
    b = y0 - (m * x0)
    unit_time = seconds / tests
    return [unit_time * (m * x + b) for x in range(tests)]
```

Some tests:

```
times = duration_spread(4, 8, 1)
print(' '.join(f'{x:.1f}' for x in times))
# output: 0.0 1.3 2.7 4.0

times = duration_spread(5, 10, -1)
print(' '.join(f'{x:.1f}' for x in times))
# output: 4.0 3.0 2.0 1.0 0.0

times = duration_spread(5, 10, .5)
print(' '.join(f'{x:.1f}' for x in times))
# output: 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0
```

### Code review

Very short since @Reinderien covered most of the ground.

- **Input type**: `tests` represents the number of tests, so I am not sure why it's a `float`. It should be an integer.
- **Missing return type hint**: the return type hint is missing in both functions.

Comment: It took me a while to get there, but @Reinderien 's explanation of the formula for sum of integers with a spacing parameter got me to understand where my solution was insufficient.  You point it out as well, I used the trick of dividing the range in half which doesn't allow the resulting slope to remain linear.  I knew what needed to be done for the first and last elements in the array and extrapolated (incorrectly) for the rest of the array.  Looking back; I didn't know what I didn't know -- which was the proper math behind this type of problem.

Comment: @MarcelWilson sure, this is just another way of solving the same problem. It keeps the original parameter `pct` and uses simpler math, but maybe it's less elegant than Reinderien's solution. I tried to make it as simple as possible. When you are satisfied, don't forget to accept an answer ;)